# Bootstrap Form - Why is my submit button crowding my input?

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/w0bekp8q/

```
<form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="reportee_first_name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reportee_first_name" name="reportee_first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="reportee_middle_name" class="control-label">Middle Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reportee_middle_name" name="reportee_middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="reportee_last_name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reportee_last_name" name="reportee_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="reportee_address_1" class="control-label">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reportee_address_1" name="reportee_address_1" placeholder="Address" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="reportee_address_2" class="control-label">Address 2</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reportee_address_2" name="reportee_address_2" placeholder="Address 2" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="reportee_city" class="control-label">City</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reportee_city" name="reportee_city" placeholder="City" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="reportee_zip" class="control-label">Zip</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reportee_zip" name="reportee_zip" placeholder="Zip" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="reportee_phone" class="control-label">Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reportee_phone" name="reportee_phone" placeholder="Phone" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="reportee_email" class="control-label">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="reportee_email" name="reportee_email" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

In my above JSFIDDLE, if you drag it out, you can see that my submit button butts up against the Email Address Input Box.

[image: Evidence of issue]

This is how it looks on my dev site -

[image: My dev site]

What am I missing here that causes my submit button to not have space between it and the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change the form class to form-horizontal:

```
<form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="">
```

to

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
```

**EDIT:**
when you use form class all col-md-* classes you used inside form-group will get a float: left; in large screens which causes the form-group doesn't take it's children height. so it goes to top of the root element, so the margin-bottom of the form-group will not apply exactly on above of your button and instead on top of the root element. using form-horizontal prevents that behaviour.

Comment: Yes that works as well. Just be aware it changes a lot of the padding and margins. Good catch Mohammad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but your .form-group is losing it's height from bootstraps md view port width and large. There is a few things you can do. You can apply you margin-bottom to the inner div, with the col-md-12, instead of .form-group.

```
.col-md-12 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

You can also try using col-xs-12, instead of md. Then you have consistent styles and can add the needed margins without any @media.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    .....
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Adam pointed out the redundant bootstrap classes.

Comment: Bootstrap column widths scale up so you would only have to include md if it were different than sm.

Comment: Isn't bootstrap mobile first? So it anything larger than md would have col 12 but anything smaller would be default? @adamMilecki

Comment: Yes Bootstrap 3+ is mobile first.  Setting col-md-12 only means md and lg are full width but xs and sm are default.  Setting col-sm-12 and col-md-12 is redundant.  Setting multiple widths would be used like col-xs-12 col-md-6 where the first one handles xs and sm and the second handles md and lg, since everything scales up.  Scale up implies mobile first.

Comment: Ah I understand so if we only include col-xs-12, then all view port sizes will be 12 cols. The col-md-12 is not needed. I wanted to make it consistent because the problem was occurring at a view size md. then we can apply the needed css and it solve through every view size, instead of using media queries. Thanks @AdamMilecki